# My for loop won't break, prints array infinitely

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I have a method that is supposed to spit out the contents of an array. However, when I run it, it loops infinitely.

Here's my code:

```
    public void displayAll() {
    for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

        System.out.println(cars[i]);

    }
```

What's wrong with it?

Edit: It's Java, btw.
Here's my whole code:

Main.java:

```
package csc;
import java.util.*;
import java.io.*;
public class Main {
/**
 * @param args the command line arguments
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {


    System.out.println("Welcome to the Car Database");

    Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter the size of the array:");
    int input = keyboard.nextInt();
    keyboard.nextLine();
    CarDatabase cdb = new CarDatabase(input);



    System.out.println("Enter the name of the input file:");
    cdb.readFile(keyboard.next());

    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Enter make, mpg, weight, all, or quit:");
    String command = sc.nextLine();


    while(!command.equals("quit")) {

        if(command.equals("all")) {
            cdb.displayAll();
//some other methods
} }
```

Car.java:

```
    package csc;
public class Car {

    String model;
    String make;
    double mpg;
    int weight;
    int year;

    public Car(String carModel, String carMake, double carMpg, int carWeight, int carYear) {
        model = carModel;
        make = carMake;
        mpg = carMpg;
        weight = carWeight;
        year = carYear;
    }
    /**
     *
     * @return
     */
    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return ("Model:" + model + " Make:" + make + " mpg:" + mpg + " weight:" + weight + " year:" + year);
    }
}
```

CarDatabase.java

```
    package csc;
import java.io.File;
import java.util.*;

public class CarDatabase {

    private Car[] cars;

    public CarDatabase(int s) {
        cars = new Car[s];
    }


    public void readFile(String a) throws Exception{
       Scanner sc = new Scanner(new File(a));
       Scanner sc2;
       for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {
           if (sc.hasNextLine()) {
               sc2 = new Scanner(sc.nextLine());
               sc2.useDelimiter(",");
               cars[i] = new Car(sc2.next(),sc2.next(),sc2.nextDouble(),sc2.nextInt(),sc2.nextInt());
               //System.out.println(cars[i]);
           }

       }

    }

    public void displayAll() {
        for (int i = 0; i < cars.length; i++) {

            System.out.println(cars[i]);

        }

    } //some other methods
```

The object is to take a csv file and put objects in the array and to have the user search for characteristics. Ex: make, model, mpg. But my array does loop infinitely, even when I tell it to be 10 slots or something tiny like that.

Here's some output from netbeans with 10 slots:

```
    Welcome to the Car Database
Enter the size of the array:
10
Enter the name of the input file:
cardb.csv
Enter make, mpg, weight, all, or quit:
all
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
Model:torino Make:ford mpg:17.0 weight:3449 year:70
Model:galaxie 500 Make:ford mpg:15.0 weight:4341 year:70
Model:impala Make:chevrolet mpg:14.0 weight:4354 year:70
Model:fury iii Make:plymouth mpg:14.0 weight:4312 year:70
Model:catalina Make:pontiac mpg:14.0 weight:4425 year:70
Model:ambassador dpl Make:amc mpg:15.0 weight:3850 year:70
Model:chevelle malibu Make:chevrolet mpg:18.0 weight:3504 year:70
Model:skylark 320 Make:buick mpg:15.0 weight:3693 year:70
Model:satellite Make:plymouth mpg:18.0 weight:3436 year:70
Model:rebel sst Make:amc mpg:16.0 weight:3433 year:70
```

Ad infinitum.

Comment: Can you post your whole code?

Comment: Please tag your questions with the language you're using.

Comment: From what I can see, you're missing a bracket? I don't think that's the cause though..

Comment: Your code is OK. Maybe your array is enormous.

Comment: What does "infinitely" mean? Does it loop around and start listing data from the start? Does it keep listing the same item over and over? Please post what's inside your array and what your output is.

Comment: Show the code which calls that method, perhaps it is being called infinitely.

Answer (score 1):

You don't query the user for a new command after executing `displayAll`, perhaps? This means that `command` will remain `"all"` which means the program executes `displayAll` over and over again. Try moving the line

```
String command = sc.nextLine();
```

inside the command loop.

Comment: The concept you proposed worked, but not the exact code. What I had to do was add "sc.nextLine();" after the "cdb.displayAll();" and the loop works normally. Thanks!

Comment: True, I overlooked the fact that the loop needs the command to be set before entering. I usually use a while(true) loop for command loops myself. Sorry for my little oversight and glad you figured it out!

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure that the program hangs right in this place? I don't see anything wrong with the loop. Try using debugger or debug logging to localize the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Solved by re-prompting the user after the while loop in the main class.

```
if(command.equals("all")) {
     cdb.displayAll();
     sc.nextLine();
}
```